# Backticks don't render correctly on sites with MathJax enabled

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, mathjax, character-escaping

Typing `` \` `text` `` produces

> ` `text`

rather than the expected

> ` `text`

on sites with MathJax enabled. The bug is visible in the preview and the final output.