# Why does this post show ``` at the end of a code block?

Tags: support, bug, markdown, code-formatting

[Here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/182667/72119) is a post on Game Development Stack Exchange which uses the [newish fenced code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/295232), i.e. the ones starting and finishing with a triple backquote:

````
```
[insert code here]
```
````

As you can see, the backquotes are shown at the end of the post, which is quite unusual.

[image]

I wasn't even able to [reproduce it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326046/295232) in the Sandbox. What's going on here?

Comment: Looking at the code of the question with my webdeveloper shows that the tripple backtick is inserted as quotes and not considered to be the end of the code markup.

Comment: I've seen this happen a lot at Code Review ever since they implemented the new fenced code blocks. Have you tried adding a newline behind the ```?

Comment: @Mast looks like adding a newline works, thanks. The question remains: why does the renderer on Meta work differently than on Game Dev and Code Review? Does syntax highlighting play a role?

Comment: We fix it on Code Review by adding a newline as well.

Comment: However, for some reason I can't reproduce it now.

Comment: I remember this coming up before, IIRC it only occurs on sites where MathJax is enabled, per a comment by Shog9

Comment: @CertainPerformance That would make sense.

Comment: Related?: [Backticks don't render correctly on sites with MathJax enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313053/269301)

Comment: Considering MathJax isn't enabled on a lot of sites and the MathJax delimiters are slightly different on some of the sites as well, it's perfectly possible for this problem to stay under the radar.

Comment: @Mast that could have the same root cause, yes. Another reason is probably that most MathJax-enabled sites don't see a lot of code blocks (especially not the ones with fences; Ctrl + K in the editor still uses indentation).

Comment: I just encountered this on Code Review again and as expected adding a newline behind the code block did fix it. I'm still not sure why I can't reproduce this 100% of the time, but it definitely happens *some* of the time.

Comment: Just FYI, this happens on [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) (electronics stack) as well, but not on EE.Meta.SE. Was just about to write up a question, but found this one in the process.